# Flask Postgresql array not permanently updating

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm working on a project using Flask and a PostgreSQL database, with SQLAlchemy.

I have `Group` objects which have a list of `User` IDs who are members of the group. For some reason, when I try to add an ID to a group, it will not save properly.

If I try `members.append(user_id)`, it doesn't seem to work at all. However, if I try `members += [user_id]`, the id will show up in the view listing all the groups, but if I restart the server, the added value(s) is (are) not there. The initial values, however, are.

Related code:

Adding group to the database initially:

```
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
# ...
g = Group(request.form['name'], user_id)
db.session.add(g)
db.session.commit()
```

The Group class:

```
from flask.ext.sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql import ARRAY

class Group(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "groups"
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(128))
    leader = db.Column(db.Integer)

    # list of the members in the group based on user id
    members = db.Column(ARRAY(db.Integer))

    def __init__(self, name, leader):
        self.name = name
        self.leader = leader
        self.members = [leader]

    def __repr__(self):
        return "Name: {}, Leader: {}, Members: {}".format(self.name, self.leader, self.members)

    def add_user(self, user_id):
        self.members += [user_id]
```

My test function for updating the Group:

```
def add_2_to_group():
    g = Group.query.all()[0]
    g.add_user(2)
    db.session.commit()
    return redirect(url_for('show_groups'))
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 7):

As [you have mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28977120/2076937), the `ARRAY` datatype in sqlalchemy is immutable. This means it isn’t possible to add new data into array once it has been initialised.

To solve this, create class `MutableList`.

```
from sqlalchemy.ext.mutable import Mutable

class MutableList(Mutable, list):
    def append(self, value):
        list.append(self, value)
        self.changed()

    @classmethod
    def coerce(cls, key, value):
        if not isinstance(value, MutableList):
            if isinstance(value, list):
                return MutableList(value)
            return Mutable.coerce(key, value)
        else:
            return value
```

This snippet allows you to extend a list to add mutability to it. So, now you can use the class above to create a mutable array type like:

```
class Group(db.Model):
    ...
    members = db.Column(MutableList.as_mutable(ARRAY(db.Integer)))
    ...
```

Comment: There has been a built-in [MutableList](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/extensions/mutable.html#sqlalchemy.ext.mutable.MutableList) since v1.1, so defining your own class should no longer be necessary.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the [`flag_modified`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/session_api.html?highlight=flag_modified#sqlalchemy.orm.attributes.flag_modified) function to mark the property as having changed. In this example, you could change your `add_user` method to:

```
from sqlalchemy.orm.attributes import flag_modified

# ~~~

    def add_user(self, user_id):
        self.members += [user_id]
        flag_modified(self, 'members')
```

Answer (score 1):

To anyone in the future: so it turns out that arrays through SQLAlchemy are immutable. So, once they're initialized in the database, they can't change size. There's probably a way to do this, but there are better ways to do what we're trying to do.

Comment: `ARRAY` is not immutable. It just does not track changes to it by default, so SQLA does not know that data in the session has changed and needs to be flushed / committed.

Answer (score 1):

This is a hacky solution, but what you can do is:

1. Store the existing array temporarily
2. Set the column value to None
3. Set the column value to the existing temporary array

For example:

```
g = Group.query.all()[0]
temp_array = g.members
g.members = None
db.session.commit()
db.session.refresh(g)
g.members = temp_array
db.session.commit()
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was solved by using the new reference for storing a object variable and assiging that new created variable in object variable.so, Instead of updating the existing objects variable it will create a new reference address which reflect the changes.

Here in Model,

```
 Table: question


optional_id = sa.Column(sa.ARRAY(sa.Integer), nullable=True)
```

In views,

```
        option_list=list(question.optional_id if question.optional_id else [])

        if option_list:
            question.optional_id.clear()
            option_list.append(obj.id)
            question.optional_id=option_list
        else:
            question.optional_id=[obj.id]
```